# How to get FedEx Shipping Price based on weight for multiple services at the page of checkout of my website when customer go to purchase the products

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods, shipping-address, fedex, currency-rates

How can i get Shipping Price based on weight for multiple services at the page of checkout of my website when customer go to purchase the products. I am using Magento, and my requirements are https://snag.gy/CnJ8BA.jpg

Answer (score 1):

The shipping rates will be auto-populated depending on the shipping locations as per the policy of the shipping carriers.. You can customize the weight costs per unit from the shipping methods configuration though..

Comment: What's the exact issue ? Can you please elaborate..

Comment: After you have registered with Fedex, you'll get Account number, Account Key, Meter Number and Password from Fedex.. You need to enter them while configure Fedex shipping methods from the backend.. Select Sandbox mode as 'Yes' and save the settings... Refer this link for more help : http://www.cobbconsulting.net/magento-fedex-setup.html

Comment: If you have all the required details, then you're good to go..

Comment: my magento backend    https://snag.gy/IE0PMO.jpg

Comment: this is my error      https://snag.gy/e3XHpS.jpg

Comment: Not working ......................